# Splitting the large table into separate tables and making MySql Union select when needed

Tags: mysql, optimization

The mysql table contains more than 200 000 records.
Thinking to split the table "records" into tables "records_2015", "records_2016", "records_2017" etc...

The idea is that on some pages we need to select records only from table "records_2017".
On other website pages we need to select records from all tables, then we can use UNION SELECT.

We select by foreign keys.

So is this way right or we should use 1 table instead?
Maybe with UNION SELECT we make query execution time higher?

Comment: You can consider table partition. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Comment: Create proper indexes and 200k records will be close to nothing to handle.

Comment: Add your table definition with Keys, Indexes and slower query, as @JimmyB has rightly pointed out with proper table design  200 000 records is the normal data size.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* split that medium-sized table into multiple tables.  It will only complicate your code without providing any benefit.  Ditto for using `PARTITION`.

Are you doing it because of some slow queries?  Let's see the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (as it stands now).  We can probably add an index or two (probably 'composite') to make them run a lot faster.  And/or we might suggest reformulating the queries.

Comment: I'm thinking about the future. Queries are not slow yet. But what if the table size will became 500 000 or 1 000 000 rows?

Comment: @TigranHovhannisyan - 200K vs 1M, or even 10M, my Answer still applies.